# How to get back focus after TAB pressed using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I bind on change function to an input element, when I click TAB to go for next input (There is a function that update the content dynamically) then I lost the focus for the next input.

I tried many ways but I failed to activate focus on next input.

```
$(document).on("change", '.usdrate, .usdcost, ', function () {
   updateinputs();
   if($(this).attr('class') == 'usdrate'){
     //not working
     $('.usdcost').focus(); 
   }
});

function updateinputs(){
  //I create new inputs because I changed the values
  //there are many operations here
  $("#test").html('').html('<input class="usdrate"><input class="usdcost">');
}
html code:
<div id="test"><input class="usdrate"><input class="usdcost"></div>
```

Comment: I have added an answer, But i don't know what is the meaning of this line."$(document).on("change", '.usdrate, .usdcost, ', function () ", That should be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(function () {
       updateinputs();
       if($('#test').find('input').hasClass('usdrate')){
     
         $('#test').find('input').focus(); 
       }
    });
    function updateinputs(){
    
      $("#test").html('<input class="usdrate"><input class="usdcost">');
    }
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


      

<div id="test"><input class="usdrate"><input class="usdcost"></div>
```

Comment: Why not, did't you see the code snippet? You  should add the code after that update content function. Actually the question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want to do exactly.

```
$(document).on("change", '.usdrate, .usdcost, ', function () {
```

Here is a syntax error

```
$(document).on("change", '.usdrate,.usdcost', function () {
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/soonsuweb/zrjo0ou8/

Comment: '.usdrate, .usdcost, ', -> '.usdrate,.usdcost' You have a wrong csss selectquery.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by using:

```
    updateinputs();
    setTimeout(function () {
     $("#"+nextfocus).select();
    }, 50);
```